# Userscript failing silently when trying to access global variables from page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, greasemonkey

I've been reading questions and answers on Stack Overflow for years (this place practically taught me to code) but this is my first time asking a question, so please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or you need more info.

I'll also state I'm not particularly great at JavaScript and just teach myself what I need as I go along, so there's probably big holes in my knowledge.

Basically I'm working on a userscript, which is a combination of three previous scripts into one (with some extras and changes).
It works absolutely fine in TamperMonkey on Chrome, but won't work in GreaseMonkey on Firefox, despite the fact the three separate scripts all worked fine.

Here's a link to [the combined script on github/gist](https://gist.github.com/adaliabooks/bf3cbdbb56db6c107dd8)

The problem occurs when I try to access the AngularJS variable to find scopes etc.
At first Firefox gives me an error saying it's undefined, but wrapping the function in a setTimeout solves that. Now it's just failing without giving me any error.

As suggested I've tried to recreate the problem with a smaller sample of code, this seems to (not) work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    https://gist.github.com/adaliabooks/
// @version      1.0
// @description  A package of fixes, new features and changes to improve GoG.com. I fix GoG, so you don't have to!
// @author       adaliabooks
// @updateURL    https://gist.github.com/adaliabooks/bf3cbdbb56db6c107dd8/raw/
// @downloadURL  https://gist.github.com/adaliabooks/bf3cbdbb56db6c107dd8/raw/
// @include      http://www.gog.com/*
// @include      https://www.gog.com/*
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js
// @require      https://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/javascripts/attrchange.js
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_deleteValue
// ==/UserScript==


function swapManualForDownloaderLinks()
{
    console.log("Swap Links");
    var accountProductsScope = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.game-details__title')).scope();
   console.log("angular accessed successfully");
    var main = accountProductsScope.details.main;
        if(main.currentDownloads[0].manualUrl.indexOf("gogdownloader") <= -1)
        {
            console.log("Links swapped");
            for (var i = 0; i < main.currentDownloads.length; i++)
            {
                var oldLink = main.currentDownloads[i].manualUrl;
                main.currentDownloads[i].manualUrl = main.currentDownloads[i].downloaderUrl;
                main.currentDownloads[i].downloaderUrl = oldLink;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < main.extras.length; i++)
            {
                var oldLink = main.extras[i].manualUrl;
                main.extras[i].manualUrl = main.extras[i].downloaderUrl;
                main.extras[i].downloaderUrl = oldLink;
            }
            accountProductsScope.$apply();
            $('.game-link').each(function(index){
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('ng-href'));
            });
        }
}

function changeDownloadLinks()
{
  console.log("Change Download Links called");
  var downloadRows = $(".game-details__column--left");
  $('.game-details__header').parent().attrchange(
  {
    trackValues: true,
    callback: function(event)
    {
      if (event.attributeName == "class")
      {
        if (!(event.newValue === "ng-hide"))
        {
          console.log("Game Details Loaded");
          swapManualForDownloaderLinks();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

changeDownloadLinks();
```

I'm thinking the problem is something to do with GreaseMonkey and how it sandboxes the script, but I'm not sure entirely what or if it's fixable...

I managed to get around this by setting my own global variable `angular` and setting it to `unsafeWindow.angular` but there's another global variable from the page I need access to (`gogData`) which won't work even when prefixed by `window` or `unsafeWindow`.

The really puzzling thing is that it works in Chrome and that [the original script](https://gist.github.com/adaliabooks/3dd8624a2dd72a7209fe) this piece of code is taken from worked in Firefox and could access these variables fine. It also works if I call the offending lines from the console.

So any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Having tried the sample above with the `@grant` set to none it works, so it's definitely to do with GreaseMonkey's security settings... But is there a solution or work around?

Comment: Two recommendations. First, simplify your example to as few lines of code as possible. Make it a toy example or a proof-of-concept about some behavior you don't understand. Doing this will help you isolate the problem but also help people who are trying to help you. Second, move that code into the question. SO questions are meant to be standalone.

Comment: can you show the controller context?

Comment: @gwg thanks, I'll see what I can do. The problem is I'm not really sure why I can't access the variable from this particular script, as they worked fine in another but I'll see if I can recreate it in isolation.

Comment: @henriqueyah I'm not sure what you mean.. I know next to nothing about Angularjs as before making these scripts I'd never even heard of it. All that side of it is on the website my script modifies (gog.com)

Comment: whole patch would be a lot simpler if you just used event delegation

Comment: @charlietfl I've just looked up event delegation, but I'm not sure how it would help in this instance, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: as far as changing the href, wait until it's clicked and do it then. Thus, using delegation can target all the elements even when they don't exist yet

Comment: @charlietfl ok, I see. I'm not sure it would help in this instance as the links don't have a set format (most of them do, but the installers use a different name for the two links) so I have to look up what link to change it to, but I don't know what the other link is just from the `<a>` / `href`, I just found it easier to look it up through the angular scopes where the info was stored and change it that way.

Comment: ok...can still get the scope data inside a click handler if that helps `this.scope()`

Comment: @charlietfl that might help.. although I think the scopes were a bit missed up (the one I wanted wasn't the one I got when I called `.scope()` on the links...)

Comment: BTW, I think with `@grant unsafeWindow` in Firefox you should [export the function](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/#user-content-exportfunction) into page scope to allow it access the page variables.

Comment: @wOxxOm proper use of unsafeWindow has solved some of the issues (such as the one in my example above) but there are still other bits that aren't working, exporting the function sounded like it might work, but it doesn't pick up the angular variable when exported...